# How do I remove a merge in the middle of my git log?

Tags: git, command-line-interface

I have a log of 40 commits in a branch and am trying to delete a 2 merges that are in the middle of the git history.
(e.g

> commit 1
> commit 2
> merge develop into branch
> commit 4
> commit 5
> merge develop into branch
> commit 6
> )

I have tried `git rebase -i <commit id>` but merges don't seem to show up. Is there a better way to approach this than reseting the head and branching off and adding newer commits? I feel as though this would be super tedious!

Comment: If you want to remove all the merges, your rebase should work, recreating the history with all the commits but no merges. If you want to remove some merges and keep others, add `--rebase-merges`.

Comment: If the beauty of your history doesn't really matter you can simply revert the two commits.